# Getting error while retrieving keys from NiFi cache

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

We are trying to retrieve keys from NiFi cache which is being frequently used and having a large number of entries. However we are getting error

```
java -jar groovy-all-2.4.13.jar dcache.groovy xxxxxxx.systems.xx.xxxx 9999 keys | wc -l
Caught: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
        at java_io_DataInput$readInt.call(Unknown Source)
        at dcache$_run_closure1$_closure5.doCall(dcache.groovy:141)
        at dcache$_run_closure1.doCall(dcache.groovy:140)
        at dcache.run(dcache.groovy:44)
5097
```

We are not familiar with groovy. However this command works with another cache with less entries and which is not frequently used. This is the code we are using

```
def dos = new DataOutputStream(output)
  def dis = new DataInputStream(input)
          dos.writeUTF('keySet')
          dos.flush()
          int numKeys = dis.readInt()
          (0..numKeys-1).each { 
            def length = dis.readInt()
            def bytes = new byte[length]
            dis.readFully(bytes)
            println new String(bytes)
          }
```

Comment: This question might be too broad, given the current details. An EOF exception could be a whole lot of stuff.

Comment: the error says the issue in line `141`.